# PHP insert in file

Tags: php

I have to insert text to a file at a specific position without reading/writing the entire file. Is that possible using just php?

```
mytext.txt content is 123456789

<?php
$message='new';
$file='mytext.txt';
$fh = fopen($file, 'rw+');
fseek($fh, 3);
fwrite($fh, $message);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

This code overwrites at the specified location.
I'm looking for '0123new456789' not '123new789'

Comment: If you need to write to a specific spot you have to read, modify and then write to the file.

Comment: no. you can't split into the middle of a file. you can fseek/fwrite, but you'll just overwrite what's there. you'll have to start a new file, copy the first bit, output your new stuff, copy the last bit.

Comment: Hey there! You should consider voting an answer as your final answer. This will give users more motivation to answer your tough questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want to do is possible without reading the file first. This should help, though:

```
// Get file contents
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// Split your strings
$beginning = substr($contents, 0, 4);
$ending = substr($contents, 4, 6);
// Re-write contents
$contents = $beginning . $message . $end;
// Write file contents
file_put_contents($file, $contents);
```

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice.
fopen() allways put the pointer at the beginning or end of file. In any case you must to pass trough the file untill you find what you are looking for. There you can close. 
See the document about it http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

By the way, fseek($fh, 3) is not mean to find 3. Is is retrieve something in the 3 bytes length. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php